# How to put one image at bottom in a tabhost

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this app that uses a tabhost and I use an ActivityGroup for each tab, because I need to call another activities.

I want to put an image at the bottom, and that image needs to be displayed in each screen, what I did is to add a RelativeLayout after the tabcontent in the xml, and put alignParentBottom=true, and it works in all the screens except the ones that have a scroll layout. How can i fix this?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" >
    </TabWidget>

    <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Thank you

Finally I figure it out, I moved the image outside the tabhost and set tabhost weight to 1, and it worked ;). Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#FFFFFFFF" >
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml layout so we can look